# How to replace WHILE with Timer

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I have that code and I need to replace WHILE with Timer to do work periodically.

Is it possible?

```
 private CancellationTokenSource ts = new CancellationTokenSource();

 public void Start()
        {
            CancellationToken ct = ts.Token;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    // do some heavy work here
                    Thread.Sleep(200);


                    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        // another thread decided to cancel
                        Debug.WriteLine("task canceled");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }, ct);

            // Simulate waiting 3s for the task to complete
            // Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            // Can't wait anymore => cancel this task 
            ts.Cancel();
        }
```

Comment: The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) page for this is pretty descriptive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the following should do the trick:

```
private CancellationTokenSource ts = new CancellationTokenSource();

public void Start()
{
    System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();
    t.Interval = 200;
    t.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (ts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // another thread decided to cancel
            Debug.WriteLine("task canceled");
            t.Stop();
        }
    }
    t.Start();
}

public void Stop()
{
    // Can't wait anymore => cancel this task 
    ts.Cancel();
}
```

You don't need the threading any more because the timer is on a separate thread already.

Comment: @ClarkKent, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: @LewsTherin, it took me a moment to get that, but then it was hilarious!